# IntelliJ IDEA: How to import Copyright settings?

Tags: intellij-idea

The team obviously needs to have the same code style, inspections and copyright settings in the IDE. Although I don't see how copyright settings could be imported into a file and then shared in the team. Is there any way to import copyright settings the similar way we import code style settings?

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at this Intellij [*FAQ*](http://devnet.jetbrains.com/docs/DOC-1186) about committing the .idea folder into the repository.

The copyright settings (made, as you noted, via *File -> Settings -> Copyright*) are Project Level settings and are accordingly stored in the `.idea/copyright` folder. If you were to check-in that folder (or the whole .idea folder with the exceptions noted in the FAQ), then it would be available to the team.

Answer (score 1):

If you go to Settings > File Templates, you can configure each file to contain a copyright notice in its header. You can also configure such notices for inner classes, etc, in Settings > Live Templates (create a macro that your team is trained to use when creating an inner class). Both file templates and live templates can be exported/imported as settings.

Comment: Good workaround. But I was more thinking of sharing File -> Settings -> Copyright setup. It's not only about inserting it to new files, using Copyright settings also allows to update copyright on commit automatically...

Answer (score 0):

You could have a look at the [Copyright Plugin](http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/88?pr=).

It's been a while that I used it, but I remember that you can configure it to apply a consistent copyright messages on any java files that you modify.

Comment: I just checked that IntelliJ natively supports the Copyright functionality since v. 8.1+ ( See [**this**](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/generating-and-updating-copyright-notice.html)), and that could be the reason why, that plugin was last updated 5 years back.

Comment: That's great info, thanks Ashutosh. 5 years ago was about the last time I used the plugin too :)

Answer (score 0):

The ***Copyright*** plugin comes pre-bundled in the newer versions of IntelliJ. And yes, using this plugin, it is possible to import copyright settings into the IDE as detailed in the [official docs](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/copyright.html#import-copyright-profile).

Additionally, it is also possible to create several copyright profiles (with varying contents) that can be applied to different scopes (set of files/packages). Formatting options for the copyright text, auto update of the text on file changes (such as to use the latest year, etc.) and much more, can also be done.